# EF Lambda Query - calculation for each item?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am getting a collection of items using a service.  I want to calculate distance from a geography coordinate for each item in the results but I don't know how to add that to the existing service query using lambda.

This is how I'm getting the data:

```
IEnumerable<Listing> items = await _listingService.Query(x => x.CategoryID 
        == model.CategoryID || keys.Any(c => c == x.CategoryID))
                    .Include(x => x.ListingPictures)
                    .Include(x => x.Category)
                    .SelectAsync();
```

This is how I would get the distance using `LINQ` but this is using the `items` collection after the above statement is run:

```
double lat = 41.2;
double lon = -71.01;
DbGeography point = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat));

List<Listing> items1 = new List<Listing>(from g in items
                          let distance = g.Geolocation.Distance(point)
                          orderby distance
                          select new Listing()
                             {
                                 ID = g.ID,                               
                                 CategoryID = g.CategoryID,
                                 Title = g.Title,
                                 Description = g.Description,
                                 Price = g.Price,
                                 Location = g.Location,
                                 Created = g.Created,
                                 DistanceInMiles = (distance / 1609.344),
                             });
    items = items1;
```

This doesn't work because it loses all the relationships from the `Include()` statements in the first query.  I can't figure out how to do the same using something like this `let` keyword in the first service lambda query.  I'm trying not to query twice.  Is there a way to calculate a field in that first service query lambda so I could add the distance to each item?

I thought using [projections](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/) might work but I couldn't get it to.

Comment: There is no way for it to "lose" the Includes, what makes you think that is happening?

Comment: @DavidG  When I use the `_listingService.Query` with `Include(x => x.ListingPictures)` for example, each item in the `item` collection contains `ListingPictures` (count>0).  After I run the second linq query using the `let clause` and `select new projection`, `ListingPictures` on each `item` are empty.  Seems to make sense because the `selecte new` projection is creating a `Listing` object but not creating the related entities for each Listing.

Comment: I'll probably have to use joins in my linq statement or some kind of nesting in the select new to keep the related property collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items1` is a completely new set of `Listing` object, you are not "updating" values of the existing one. So because you don't copy over the `ListingPictures` and `Category` properties, they will be null. You need to do something like this in your projection:

```
select new Listing()
{
    ID = g.ID,                               
    CategoryID = g.CategoryID,
    Title = g.Title,
    Description = g.Description,
    Price = g.Price,
    Location = g.Location,
    Created = g.Created,
    DistanceInMiles = (distance / 1609.344),
    ListingPictures = g.ListingPictures, //Add this line
    Category = g.Category //and this line
});
```

Alternatively, it looks like you are just trying to update the `DistanceInMiles` property, that may be better done with a simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think using linq in this case will make your statement less readable but below is how you do it:

```
List<Listing> items1 = items.Select(g => select new Listing()
                             {
                                 ID = g.ID,                               
                                 CategoryID = g.CategoryID,
                                 Title = g.Title,
                                 Description = g.Description,
                                 Price = g.Price,
                                 Location = g.Location,
                                 Created = g.Created,
                                 DistanceInMiles = (g.Geolocation.Distance(point) / 1609.344),
                             });
```

Comment: Looks similar to the linq statement I'm already using but doesn't address the relationships issue.  How do I populate `ListingPictures` as it's being done with `.Include(x => x.ListingPictures)`?

Comment: Both queries are Linq queries, yours called the query syntax and mine is the lambda syntax. `ListingPictures` was already included in items why would you care about it again?